# Solving modular matrix equations via Gaussian elimination or System of linear equations (SIS assumption?)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

Suppose $S \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m \times m}$, and the norm of $S$ is less than an upper-bound $\beta$. i.e., the norm of $S$ is short.

Additionally, $A_1, \cdots, A_k, C_1, \cdots, C_k \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m \times n}$.

Here, $k \geq m>n$, and $q$ is a large prime.

And $S$ is unknown.

The following equations are satisfied

$SA_1 = C_1$ 
$SA_2 = C_2$ 
$\vdots$ 
$SA_k = C_k$

Can I solve this problem by using Gaussian elimination or any method of system of linear equations?

Note that I think this problem is similar with the lattice hard assumption - SIS. 
I am not sure whether this problem has a solution.